# Python: Search for DateTime inside a Dictionary that is Less than a certain DateTime

Tags: python, datetime

If I have the following data:

```
>data1 = ({'StartDT':'2017-01-01 04:54:00'},{'EndDT':'2017-01-01 08:56:00'},{'Code':'1234'})

>data2 = ({'StartDT':'2017-01-01 05:54:00'},{'EndDT':'2017-01-01 07:45:00'},{'Code':'1234'})
```

Question 1 = In Python, what do you think is the best **data structure** for this?

Question 2 = My goal is to **search for data(n)** which has a **StartDT which is less than** a certain DateTime *(example: '2017-01-01 06:30:00)*, and whose **EndDT is greater than** that certain DateTime.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about a list? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Serge, I'm a newbie in Python.  I checked out the "list of dictionaries" and it seems to be a good structure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach to the problem.

```
# First, let's put data in a more useful format...
data = [{'StartDT': '2017-01-01 04:54:00',
         'EndDT': '2017-01-01 08:56:00',
         'Code': '1234'},
        {'StartDT': '2017-01-01 05:54:00',
         'EndDT': '2017-01-01 07:45:00',
         'Code': '1234'}]

# Convert the date string to datetime (you should really do this as you insert
# the dictionaries into the list...
from datetime import datetime

def convert_timestamp(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for d in data:
    d['StartDT'] = convert_timestamp(d['StartDT'])
    d['EndDT'] = convert_timestamp(d['EndDT'])

# Next you can use filter and a function to help pick off the entries that
# meet your needs.

start_time = convert_timestamp('2017-01-01 05:30:00')
end_time = convert_timestamp('2017-01-01 08:30:00')

matching = filter(lambda d: d['StartDT'] < start_time and d['EndDT'] > end_time,
                  data)

print(repr(list(matching)))

# This could be rewritten as...
def is_out_of_range(start, end, d):
    return d['StartDT'] < start and d['EndDT'] > end

# We use partial() to add the start and end parameters, which leaves a function
# with one parameter left.  That will be the data passed in by filter.
from functools import partial
matching = filter(partial(is_out_of_range, start_time, end_time), data)

# Alternatively, you could avoid the partial with a lambda:
matching = filter(lambda d: is_out_of_range(start_time, end_time, d), data)

print(repr(list(matching)))
```

You definitely want to use a different organization for your data (a list of dictionaries), and you'll need to convert your strings to something more useful (datetime instances).  That allows you to iterate through the data much better and do the matching you want.

Comment: Thanks jszakmeister, that is very informative. I will try that style, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

I think the best structure here is to use Class. For example, 
def class TimePeriod():

```
def TimePeriod():
  def __init__(self, start_dt, end_dt, code):
    self.start_dt = start_dt
    self.end_dt = end_dt
    self.code = code
```

Of course, you can use ```dict`` instead of your custom class, but having custom objects here just gives you more clarity.

**Q2**

Any search in the unsorted array takes `O(n)` time. So your function might look like this

```
start_dt_val = datetime....
end_dt_val = datetime....

def predicate_less_than(element):
  # element is TimePeriod class
  return element.start_dt < start_dt_val and \
          element.end_dt > end_dt_val


def find_element_with_predicate(arr, predicate):
  for el in arr:
    if predicate(el):
      return el


t1 = TimePeriod(....)
...
tn = ...

arr = [t1, ..., tn]

el = find_element_with_predicate(arr, predicate_less_than)
```

`el` will be `None` if no element would be found.

Comment: Thanks Vitaly!  I'll do some experiments using your sample.

Comment: Be sure that all your `start_dt` and `end_dt` are `datetime` class. In your example, they are Python strings. Take a look at [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib to work with datetimes in Python.

Comment: Noted. I'll convert them and see what will happen.